# Converting exchange rates in pandas dataframe to GBP

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this. I'm trying to convert these stock prices to the corresponding exchange rates and output them into GBP.

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'Stock': ['AAPL', 'AAL', 'BBW', 'BBY'],
                        'Price': [123, 21, 15, 311],
                        'Currency': ['USD', 'CAD', 'EUR', 'GBP'],
                        'Date': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04'],
                        'USD': [1.6, 1.5, 1.55, 1.57],
                        'CAD': [1.7, 1.79, 1.75, 1.74],
                        'EUR': [1.17, 1.21, 1.18, 1.19],
                        'GBP': [1, 1, 1, 1]})
```

I want to multiply the stock price for each row so for example since AAPL is in USD I want it to be multiplied by 1.6 so it is converted into GBP, and the end output I am trying to get is something that would look like this.

```
df_end = pd.DataFrame({'Stock': ['AAPL', 'AAL', 'BBW', 'BBY'],
                       'Price': [123, 21, 15, 311],
                       'Currency': ['USD', 'CAD', 'EUR', 'GBP'],
                       'Date': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04'],
                       'USD': [1.6, 1.5, 1.55, 1.57],
                       'CAD': [1.7, 1.79, 1.75, 1.74],
                       'EUR': [1.17, 1.21, 1.18, 1.19],
                       'GBP': [1, 1, 1, 1],
                       'GBP value': [196.8, 37.59, 17.7, 311]})
```

Any help at all on this would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: is your data string-typed? Should they be numerical?

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes they should be numerical I changed it now thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

This used to be `.lookup` which is deprecated in Pandas 1.2.0. A way around this is `get_indexer`:

```
idx = df_test.columns.get_indexer(df_test['Currency'])
df_test['GBP val'] = df_test['Price'] * df_test.values[df.index, idx]
```

Output:

```
  Stock  Price Currency        Date   USD   CAD   EUR  GBP GBP val
0  AAPL    123      USD  2020-01-01  1.60  1.70  1.17    1   196.8
1   AAL     21      CAD  2020-01-02  1.50  1.79  1.21    1   37.59
2   BBW     15      EUR  2020-01-03  1.55  1.75  1.18    1    17.7
3   BBY    311      GBP  2020-01-04  1.57  1.74  1.19    1     311
```

Comment: TIL about the `.get_indexer()` method. +1

Comment: @ShugoChara12 you have inverted your Fx rates. GBP is worth more than USD, AAPL USD in GBP terms should be worth less in GBP currency. Just in case.

Answer (score 0):

```py
df_test["GBP value"] = df_test.apply(
    lambda x: x["Price"] * x[x["Currency"]], axis=1
)
print(df_test)
```

Prints:

```
  Stock  Price Currency        Date   USD   CAD   EUR  GBP  GBP value
0  AAPL    123      USD  2020-01-01  1.60  1.70  1.17    1     196.80
1   AAL     21      CAD  2020-01-02  1.50  1.79  1.21    1      37.59
2   BBW     15      EUR  2020-01-03  1.55  1.75  1.18    1      17.70
3   BBY    311      GBP  2020-01-04  1.57  1.74  1.19    1     311.00
```